# How to download Firefox 34 onto Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I'm new to Linux in general and I have problems updating Firefox 34, every time I go to the Firefox website and hit download, the Firefox download just turns into a file. What should I do, my Ubuntu is a 64 bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I messed up Firefox, now it's not opening, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/564022/i-messed-up-firefox-now-its-not-opening-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to either open the Ubuntu Software Center and look for Firefox, or run `sudo apt-get install firefox` in a terminal.

Most software that you'll need can be downloaded from a central repository, that you can search through the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of saiarcot895 is the safest one. However, it is possible you want a newer version of Firefox than the standard repositories of Ubuntu deliver. Make sure you have downloaded the right version of Firefox. This should be a .deb file. Right-click the file and select "Open with Software Center". Now you can install this program from the Software Center. Remember there may be a reason why this version is not available from the standard repositories, maybe it is not compatible with your Ubuntu version.